# Webex guest issuer integration with widgets -- Create team web api issue

Tags: c#, jquery, webex

I am trying to create a Webex team using the following process. But not working. I had created JWT token and exchanged it for  access token which I had passed in to the Authorization header in the API call. But I keep getting the error message that I mentioned below. And another fact is I can execute the same API with GET method which returns the number of teams I had.I had followed steps in the webex developer site. But I can't create the team.

```
Request URL: 
https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/teams
Request Method: 
POST
```

The following is the header that I passed to the API

Accept: 
application/json

Content-Type: 
application/json

Authorization: 
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.VNUms24YsiwNbU_KN0Y7v1osAilq1MMiIQn6DRnyNitJAgeTLuyrwiYM0JIaox-dQxQKBp897uAj9vksg0ik2-j2MddcRmx4gsVF787uw7VpCIiZNNME346__xddvmmttna7IErBTz84hqZsnvSlmKLpus4lQs_k9I8ZHTsuPJ9FRXPry6ZAmPjDk1uWGGWFXyOSgH-VkDj9hY9Fy_6r7MKIn0YV21dxIKaZVZ6DMo1NSJM68I-90Vv-QbQY3gBeH25ZXDNDDBJg6-woMF2QPk_N8zrL8G1WPRXxGAA_lqGr_qGq65CfOwuqGikpLsRtjhWU4sYDX3xrK918W08CFw

This is the parameter I passed to the API

name=hearingteam

This is the server response 
{"message":"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.","errors":[{"description":"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax."}],"trackingId":"ROUTER_5CEB64F0-FC8D-01BB-05C2-7AA62A6905C2"}

Answer (score 0):

The API requires parameters to be passed in JSON format.

Eg : JSON.stringyfy({"name":"hearingteam"});